# existence of generator set of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

I always find this quote in the books of linear algebra:
"Let V be an K-vector space and S a spanning set of V"

My question is simple, why does S exist?

Answer (score 5):

One can take $S = V$.  Slightly less trivially, one can take $S = V\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: thank you man for your answer.